# 17n^2+5n^3 in Big-Omega notation

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity

Question is in the title:

I have gathered that the Big-Oh is

> O(n<sup>3</sup>).

As that would represent the highest degree of the polynomial.  And the worst case time complexity.

By contridiction dose Big-Omega mean lowest degree? i.e

> Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)

if that is the case, how can we justify disregarding the 3rd degree?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Big-O does not really say what the biggest degree is; that's just a quick rule - and Big-Omega does not say what the lowest degree is. `O` and `Omega` are really tools for *comparing two functions*, not for saying something about one function.

When we say that `f = O(g)`, it means that the function `f` does not grow faster than `g` (when constant factors are disregarded). So `17n^2 + 5n^3 = O(n^3)`, but it is also the case that `17n^2 + 5n^3 = O(n^4)`, `17n^2 + 5n^3 = O(n^5)`, and `17n^2 + 5n^3 = O(18036523n^38576)` - but it is not the case that `17n^2 + 5n^3 = O(n^2.9999999)`.

When we say that `f = Omega(g)`, it means that the function `f` does not grow slower than `g` (when constant factors are disregarded). So `17n^2 + 5n^3 = Omega(n^3)`, and `17n^2 + 5n^3 = O(n^2)`, and `17n^2 + 5n^3 = O(n)`, and `17n^2 + 5n^3 = O(1)`, but it is not the case that `17n^2 + 5n^3 = O(n^3.000001)`.

So if you want a quick rule, it is that `f = O(g)` if the highest degree of `f` is `<=` the highest degree of `g`, and `f = Omega(g)` if the highest degree of `f` is `>=` the highest degree of `g`.

Comment: So you could say that F = Ω(n2) because f cannot grow slower then n^2. In this case, it would be correct to says that anything less then ^3 would also be correct.  But, as a general guild line we take the first degree below the MAX degree?

Comment: @Special--k: Anything less than _or equal to_ n^3 is correct, and one generally prefers a so-called "tight bound", which is to use _the_ greatest degree. So the preferred answers are actually `O(n^3)` and `Omega(n^3)`.